# displaying pdf file after installation

Tags: c#, winforms

I had windows application which check if adobe acrobat installed in pc or not if it installed pdf file will display from cd if it is not installed installer window appear to setup the acrobat and then the pdf file displayd  I did my code will but I want when runing installer (process.start()) the pdf file didnot display and after finising setup the pdf file displdayed.

```
private void OK_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        try
        {
            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                switch (d.DriveType)
                {

                    case DriveType.CDRom:
                        Process myProcess = new Process();
                        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = d.Name + "AdbeRdr90_en_US";
                        myProcess.Start();
                        AfterStube();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Pleas Eject All Virtual CD-ROMs");

        }




    }


 private void AfterStube()
    {

        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();


        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            switch (d.DriveType)
            {
                case DriveType.CDRom:
                    Process myProcess = new Process();
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = d.Name + "lamp.pdf";

                    myProcess.Start();
                    panel1.Hide();
                    panel2.Show();

                    break;

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it really so difficult to reformat your code so it is readable here? Make it easy to read your question, and you will get answers faster.

Comment: What about people who refuse to use Adobe products?  Couldn't you check to see if there was a program that can simple open a *.pdf file instead?  I am in one of those groups who will never trust Adobe with being on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... it's hard to understand what you want, but maybe you want to wait until acrobat installation is finished? If so, try doing this:

```
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

With this your application will wait for acrobat to be installed and then call AfterStube() to display pdf file.